# Unsafe conversion between identical struct types where only tags differ

Tags: go

Consider two types identical in structure but differing in their tags:

```
type Foo struct {
  Id int64 `json:"-"`
}

type Bar struct {
  Id int64 `json:"id"`
}
```

Unfortunately Go's idiom forbids casting between two types when their tags differ and for good reason.  However I still need to be able to control the data that is serialised to JSON and don't want to use `interface{}` types.

My question is, how safe is it to use golang's `unsafe.Pointer` to perform casts between two types which are identical in structure (but not tags)?  Something like:

```
rf := &Foo{1}
rb := (*Bar)(unsafe.Pointer(rf))
```

Is there **any** chance at all of a panic ensuing maybe because internally the data in each of the two types is held slightly differently due to the tags differing **or** is the information about tags held separate from the actual type data and data in each of the types is structurally identical?

**EDIT**

For clarification I should mention that although the example provided above employs single-field structs, the question is really about struct types containing multiple fields.

Comment: Why not just copy struct Foo into struct Bar, either manually (field by field) or via reflecting over the fields? What is the reason the tags differ?

Comment: @elithrar: I'm trying to avoid manually copying and using interface{} or reflection.  The tags differ because the application I'm working on has different user types and it may be the case that some struct fields should not be available to all user types.

Comment: @miguelg if they are really identical I suppose it would be ok, as the tags are saved as part of the type info, not the data of the object. It is, though, of course, *unsafe* :)

Comment: If some struct fields don't apply, selectively embed a second struct into your User struct as needed. Use Marshal/Unmarshal logic or `omitempty` tags to choose how to omit that struct when you leave it `nil`.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I take `unsafe` to mean "the safety is guaranteed by the programmer" more than "actually unsafe". For instance, converting an `f64` to its bits as a `uint64` via unsafe cannot in any sane implementation of the language actually be unsafe. Which is kinda why `math` does it that way. There are, of course, times when it is actually unsafe because it relies on ephemeral OS or compiler details, but that's just because `unsafe` lets you do potentially unsafe things, not that anything done with unsafe is inherently bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Strictly** speaking, this isn't safe. The reason is that the relevant section of the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) doesn't give any guidelines for memory layout for structs. It doesn't guarantee in-memory field ordering, packing, or alignment. In theory, a compiler could, based on optimization info, decide two seemingly identical structs are to be represented differently based on their usage. This could even be a Heisenbug where the offending optimization doesn't happen in `go test` builds.

**Practically** speaking, this is unlikely to happen in any real compiler and you can probably do it safely. This is especially true of one field structs like the one you provided. You should probably ensure through profiling that copying is insufficient before you go doing this though.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately Go's idiom forbids casting between two types when their tags differ and for good reason

The [release notes for Go 1.8](https://beta.golang.org/doc/go1.8) (currently in beta) seems to indicate this restriction is now lifted:

> ### Changes to the language
>
> When explicitly converting a value from one struct type to another, as of Go 1.8 the tags are ignored.
>   **Thus two structs that differ only in their tags may be converted from one to the other**:

```
func example() {
    type T1 struct {
        X int `json:"foo"`
    }
    type T2 struct {
        X int `json:"bar"`
    }
    var v1 T1
    var v2 T2
    v1 = T1(v2) // now legal
}
```